# Load jquery get load

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, load

How can i do this with jquery load

```
.../article/relates.html?longitude=45.34554...
```

I am on rails, and my controller respond with the following codes

```
  @Article = Article.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
```

Here my jquery

```
$( "#dialog" ).load('/events/relates#eventconfirm', { data: 'hello' });
```

I keep getting a 400 error though and not sure why!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Be sure to specify the right URL.** Your first code snippet uses `/article/` as the path. Your second uses `/events/`.
2. **Be sure to specify the correct parameters.** Again, there is an inconsistency between the two examples: `longitude` versus `data`.

Those two, separately or in combination, may be why you are receiving a "400 - Bad Request" error response code.

Comment: Ok no i understand, but just setting data: 'hello' the page freeze, but if i leave it out it works fine